# Trigger to count the number of assets based on record type from child accounts and display in Parent

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement where i cannot find an solution. Can anyone pls help me on this.

Requirement - I have a number field in Account and if this account has 3 child accounts, then the assets related to these 3 accounts should be calculated and updated in parent account field.

Example - Account name - ABC
if ABC has 2 child accounts
child 1 - has 3 assets varies by record type
child 2 - has 2 assets varies by record type

Then ABC account custom field should be populated with the value as "5" if all 5 assets falls under same record Type

code:

```
trigger RollupAsset on Asset (before insert,before update,after delete, after insert, after update) {
List<id> accIdList = new List<id>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
        For(Asset AsV : Trigger.new){
            if(Asv.AccountId!=null){
                accIdList.add(AsV.Account.ParentId);
            }
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        For(Asset AsV : Trigger.new){
            if(Asv.AccountId!=null){
                accIdList.add(AsV.Account.ParentId);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    Map<Id,Account> CountMap = new Map<Id,Account>();
    List<aggregateResult> results=[select Count(Id) ,Account.ParentId ParentValue from Asset where Account.parentId=:accIdList and RecordTypeId='012f20000005QG0' group by Account.ParentId];
    
    for (AggregateResult ar : results){
        
        Integer rowvalue = 0;
        
        Id ParentAccountValue = null;
        ParentAccountValue = (Id)ar.get('ParentValue');    
        
        if (!CountMap.containskey(ParentAccountValue)){
            
            For(Account acc : [SELECT id,Count_of_Active_WeatherTRAK_Subscription__c FROM Account WHERE id =: accIdList]){
                if(CountMap.containskey(acc.id)){
                    countMap.get(acc.Id).Count_of_Active_WeatherTRAK_Subscription__c = acc.Assets.Size();
                    accUpdateList.add(countMap.get(acc.Id));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try{
        update accUpdateList;
    }Catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You have a SOQL in for loop are you looking for a solution to remove that? what is the error you are getting now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just restructure the Account update piece. You don't need a for loop there and just get the count of assets and populate in your custom fields value.

```
trigger RollupAsset on Asset (before insert,before update,after delete, after insert, after update) {
List<id> accIdList = new List<id>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
        For(Asset AsV : Trigger.new){
            if(Asv.AccountId!=null){
                accIdList.add(AsV.Account.ParentId);
            }
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        For(Asset AsV : Trigger.new){
            if(Asv.AccountId!=null){
                accIdList.add(AsV.Account.ParentId);
            }
        }
    }
    
    List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    List<aggregateResult> results=[select Count(Id) assetCount, Account.ParentId ParentValue from Asset where Account.parentId=:accIdList and RecordTypeId='012f20000005QG0' group by Account.ParentId];
    
    for (AggregateResult ar : results){
        Id ParentAccountValue = (Id)ar.get('ParentValue');    
        Integer numOfAssets = (Integer)ar.get('assetCount');
        accUpdateList.add(new Account(Id = ParentAccountValue, Count_of_Active_WeatherTRAK_Subscription__c = numOfAssets);
    }
    try{
        update accUpdateList;
    }Catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
    }
    
}
```